# regex to match string in between words and special charatcer

Tags: regex

I have the following logs

> Line: 1111: xyz: SOME_DEV_: somelog..
>
> Line; 222: dd: LL_dev-: somelog...
>
> Line; 333: gg0 main_prod-: log..
>
> Line; 444: yy- %*test1*: log,,
>
> Line; 555: mnmii %*test2*: log..
>
> Line; 7777: mfasnm: %*PROD*: ERROR_LOG

I need to filter line with dev and prod irrespective of case and speacial characters before and after them.
I tried this but did not work

```
\b(dev|prod)\b
```

Comment: `_` is a *word*, not a special character. `\b` only matches between word and non-word chars (or start/end of string). See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DAJveE/1).

Comment: `/%.?(dev|prod).*: ERROR_LOG$/gmi` https://regex101.com/r/bPlDce/1

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I am sorry.I did not update properly. after dev or prod there could be anything and before that also.

Comment: @DotNetDev19 if what you're saying is correct (I don't think so) than you can easily get false positives.`deviant` << see the dev?

Comment: *after dev or prod there could be anything and before that also.* - so why use word boundaries? Remove them, `(dev|prod)` will do.